# Regular expression to match the different calendar date format dates "M{0,1,2}/D{1,2}/Y{2,4}", "Y{4}"

Tags: python, regex, pandas

dates are given as list of strings, require a regular expression to match the different possible date formats. preferably in python

```
dates = ["04/20/2009", "04/20/09", "4/20/09","4/3/09","6/2008","12/2009","2009","2010"]
df = pd.Series(dates)
```

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried so far? Please read [ask] if you haven't already.

Comment: considering ``` re.findall('(?:[\d]{0,2}/){0,2}[\d]{2,4}', dates[i]) ``` what does ``` ?: ``` do in regex or where can I learn for details?

Comment: I forgot to mention, please [edit] the question to add details.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a regular expression.  Specify the data type:

```
import pandas as pd
dates = ["04/20/2009", "04/20/09", "4/20/09","4/3/09","6/2008","12/2009","2009","2010"]
df = pd.Series(dates,dtype='datetime64[ns]')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
0   2009-04-20
1   2009-04-20
2   2009-04-20
3   2009-04-03
4   2008-06-01
5   2009-12-01
6   2009-01-01
7   2010-01-01
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```